# Exclude loremABCipsum when grepping ABC

Tags: regex, grep

How to ignore certain results in grep?
For example, I need to find all the lines containing ABC except loremABCipsum and xyzABC123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your version of `grep` supports PCRE, use a negative lookahead:

```
grep -P '(?!=xyz|lorem)ABC(?!123|ipsum)' filename
```

Comment: ... Unless you might also have `xyzABCipsum`

Comment: @tripleee True, in that event the best bet might be `grep ABC filename | grep -vP 'xyzABC123|loremABCipsum'`

Answer (score 1):

Use pipes:

```
grep -e ABC [filename] | grep -v loremABCispum | grep -v xyzABC123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`

```
awk '/ABC/ {if (!/xyzABC123|loremABCipsum/) print}' file
```

This will print all lines with `ABC` but not if the have `xyzABC123` or `loremABCipsum`

---

A logical test version:

```
awk '{f=0} /ABC/ {f=1} /xyzABC123|loremABCipsum/ {f=0} f' file
```

Comment: This will filter out the match `ABC xyzABC123` -- not clear which way the OP wants to handle this, but I would guess it should not be filtered.

Comment: That may be the case, but can be sorted out if needed. But as I read it, he would not like lines that contains `xyzABC123|loremABCipsum` so it should be ok.